# Yii2 and php-generators (yield) with mysql

Tags: mysql, pagination, yii2, generator, yield

I have mysql table "Flats" with such rows

```
-----------------------
id | created    | rooms
-----------------------
1  | 2016-07-21 | 2
2  | 2016-07-20 | 1
3  | 2016-07-20 | 1
4  | 2016-07-19 | 2
5  | 2016-07-18 | 2
6  | 2016-07-18 | 1
7  | 2016-07-17 | 2
8  | 2016-07-17 | 1
-----------------------
```

I need to select 3 flats with 2 rooms and 4 flats with 1 room sorted by date (DESC). That selected info (3 and 4 flats) would be at the 1st site's page. Then i need to select next info (next 3 and 4 flats).

1)- How can i do it in yii2 using not pagination and not mysql offset, but using php-generators (yield).
2)- What is the better way- mysql offset or php-yield for the purpose.

Comment: I don't know even how to start this code in Yii2- how combine active query and generators

Answer (score 0):

I see no benefits in this approach. Why reinvent the wheel especially when you choose to use framework and it already provides Pagination component?

You can read about pagination in common in [Pagination](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-pagination.html) article. Example:

```
use yii\data\Pagination;

// build a DB query to get all articles with status = 1
$query = Article::find()->where(['status' => 1]);

// get the total number of articles (but do not fetch the article data yet)
$count = $query->count();

// create a pagination object with the total count
$pagination = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $count]);

// limit the query using the pagination and retrieve the articles
$articles = $query->offset($pagination->offset)
    ->limit($pagination->limit)
    ->all();
```

Links to pages are displayed with [yii\widgets\LinkPager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-linkpager.html) widget:

```
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;

echo LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $pagination,
]);
```

And there are some details for [yii\data\Pagination](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html) component.

Learn framework features and use it. For example when using `ActiveDataProvider` with `GridView` widget, the pagination is already built in, so you only configure it to fit your needs (items per page, etc.) and don't care about details of internal implementation (offsets, etc.). But it's obviously better if you understand how it works.